# Как узнать какие файлы загружает процесс?

Tags: c#

Отлаживаю приложение на C# (WPF), есть модуль исходный код которого я посмотреть не могу. Я вижу через process explorer что приложение загружает файлы, а какие конкретно не могу понять.

Есть ли какой-то для этого софт? Можно ли это как-то узнать через process explorer или через Visual Studio 2015 (нашел там профилировщик, но я им не пользовался никогда).

Спасибо!!!

Comment: Ну вообще я конечно не уверен, но должен быть какой то свой стек с I/O, ибо загрузка фалов это именно I/O, соответственно можно его вывести.

Comment: filemon вам в помощь. Файловые операции вполне показывает.